# Looking for a good online itinerary organizer / travel planner

Tags: online-resources, planning, itineraries, software

I am looking for a good itinerary organizer. I want it to be able to store and organize all the following aspects:

1. Travel details (flying, driving)
2. Accommodation details
3. Activities
4. Available online

I have found the [inspirock](http://www.inspirock.com/) website to be quite useful and easy to use but it does lack some aspects like:

1. Can't manage accommodation
2. Hard to work with not predefined activities

Any suggestions please?

Comment: This question has attracted a couple of close votes as a "travel planning" question.  I would argue that this one should stay open, since it's about useful resources for travelers;   "travel planning" questions are those in which someone asks for things to do in a particular location, how to get to/from a particular location, etc.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert The trouble is not that it is travel planning, but that broadly scoped, open-ended requests for resources are unlikely to garner a single, definitive answer and as such aren't well-suited to a Q&A site. Instead, you'll get lots of suggestions or reviews, and which anecdote is "correct" is up to the whim of the original poster. All of the things the OP seems to be asking for I normally just put into Google Calendar, and why anyone would need or want a separate service meeting these four criteria (but not, say, frequent flyer accrual or foreign language phrases) is unclear.

Answer (score 5):

Consider [TripIt](https://www.tripit.com/). You can forward pretty much every receipt/confirmation/booking email to plans@tripit.com, and it will automatically scrape them and add the details to your itinerary, which you can view on the web or in mobile apps for iOS and Android.

It doesn't have a built-in catalog of activities like inspirock does, but you can manually add events to your TripIt itinerary whenever you what. I'll sometimes fill in a TripIt itinerary with all my pre-booked reservations, then manually sprinkle in some possible activities like "maybe go to 
Palatine Hill Tuesday" to give myself some notes. You can still use inspirock, along with guidebooks and other resources, for suggested activities, but keep your master itinerary and everything booked in advance organized in TripIt. Their Pro service adds a flight tracker, among other features, but the itinerary management is all in the free version.

Another option is [Google Trips](https://get.google.com/trips/), for iOS and Android (not web), which scrapes your inbox for travel bookings and presents them along with activity suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have been happy with [Kayak](http://kayak.com).